# how to render promises coming from different files to html page using express POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise

I have some results i queried from documentdb and I want to show them on my web page. I use promises in my query functions, those functions show the results fine on the console, but when I use them within the `app.post` function, the result on the web page is `[object promise]`

### database call

```
function query(queryString, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.queryDocuments(collectionUrl, queryString).toArray((err, results) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                for (var queryResult of results) {
                    resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
                    console.log(`\tQuery returned number of ignition off events: ${resultString}`);
                    return resultString;
                }
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

### app file

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index", {action: null});
});
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    let actionText = Task.getDatabase().then(() => Task.query(usercount, Task.getCollection(config.collection.collectionIdUsers)));
    res.render("index", {action: actionText});
});
```

How do I output the results from query functions into my web page?

I hope my explanation is clear, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use async / await, you could just mark the `app.post` as an `async` function, and then use `await Task.getdatabase()`,.  Alternatively place the render the inside then callback.

Comment: You gotta resolve your `Task.query()` promise in `app.post('/')`

Comment: @oneturkmen  `You gotta resolve your Task.query()`    No promises can be chained, it's just he's not handling the returned promise in the `app.post`

Comment: This is what I meant. Apologize for misleading terms (`resolve`). I meant he needed to use `.then()`

Comment: got the answer, thanks. i am new into web development, i want to study await async, and see if it's better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see it directly in a code, you are not returning "value" you are returning Promise

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
```

So guess what is saved there - a Promise that you have returned:

```
let actionText = Task.getDatabase().then(() => Task.query(usercount,Task.getCollection(config.collection.collectionIdUsers)) );
```

You have to .then the promise to take the value from the Promise.

```
app.post("/", function (req, res) {
    Task.getDatabase()
    .then(() => Task.query(usercount,Task.getCollection(config.collection.collectionIdUsers)) )
    .then(actionText => {
        res.render('index',{action : actionText});
    })
});
```

Comment: Also, an additional `.catch(err=>res.status(500).send('Error happened!!'))` or similar wouldn't be a bad idea ;-)

Comment: thank you, it works!!

bitifet, yeah agreed, thanks also :D